# New sites for mobile OS

Tags: feature-request, sister-site

Is it possible to create a site for Windows Phone 7, iPhone, Ovi, like Android has (http://android.stackexchange.com) and a general site for mobiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic [Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) site was tried, but didn't get enough activity to make it viable.

Android questions can, as you said, be asked on [Android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com). Similarly, iPhone questions can be asked on [Apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: To elaborate on this answer a bit, yes it *is* possible to create a site through our process described in http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq. But, as @Dori said, a gadget site has been tried and failed. Someone is welcome to try again someday, but they should have strong reason to believe they can garner significantly more support for such a site than the first time around.

Comment: I get your answer for the last part of my question. What about the first part? ("Is it possible to create a site for Windows Phone 7, iphone, ovi like the android has (http://android.stackexchange.com)")

Comment: @Randall - Are you asking about individual sites for each? If so, your best bet for WP7 is to follow the [Windows Phone](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) proposal. There's no currently proposed Nokia site, but you can look at the FAQ @Robert pointed to if you think there would be sufficient interest. And as I wrote initially, iPhone questions are always welcome at [Apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are three related Area 51 proposals that would apply:

- [Windows Phone](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) (currently in [Public Beta](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/))
- <del>[Mobile Phones](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11003/mobile-phones)</del> Proposal deleted
- <del>[Mobile Device Users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26379/mobile-device-users)</del> Proposal deleted

I suggest you sign up and promote any or all of them to help get them off the ground.